# Sorl thumbnail not working [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: django, django-templates, sorl-thumbnail

I'm using sorl-thumbnail 12.2

```
{% load thumbnail %}

  {% for image in citem.get_images %}
              <div class="image-block">
                {% thumbnail image.img.path '180x180' as thumb %}
                {% thumbnail image.img.path '640x640' as medium %}
                <a data-lightbox="i-{{image.id}}" href="{{medium.url}}" title="{{citem.display_plant_smart}}">
                  <img class="img-rounded img-responsive bound-img-big" src="{{ thumb.url }}" alt="{{citem.display_plant_smart}}" style="padding-bottom: 1px"/>
                </a>
                {% endthumbnail %}
```

Usually this code was working, for some unknown reason it stops working.

Now I'm getting

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Even the file exists on disk. When trying to run sorl migrations I get this:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "thumbnail_kvstore" already exists
```

I'm using MAC and the same is happening in linux as well. I've already fake the migration with no success. The images are there in the disk.

[image]

Comment: are you using linux system?? if yes use sudo to install , and make sure to use the latest version of sorl-thumbnail which is 14.1

Comment: This looks like two different issues. The first one is cause by `citem.get_images()` returning a file name that doesn't exist. The second seems to be a broken migration. You could try running a `--fake` migration and see if that fixes it.

Comment: You should avoid asking several questions at once. And when you need help with debugging an error, always include the full traceback and a [mcve]. Without that, it's nearly impossible to help you.

Comment: @HåkenLid already did but no difference